# Python: How to measure time spent waiting for I/O?

Tags: python

I've used `profile` on functions in my Python script to get their execution time, and I've used the Unix time command to get the `real`, `user` and `sys` time of the script overall, but I can't find how to measure the time spent waiting for I/O in Python.

In my script I query various database, can I measure the time it takes to send and receive information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a [Decorator](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) like this that allows you to measure the execution times of dedicated methods  :

```
import time                                                

def measure_time(f):

  def timed(*args, **kw):
    ts = time.time()
    result = f(*args, **kw)
    te = time.time()

    print '%r (%r, %r) %2.2f sec' % \
          (f.__name__, args, kw, te-ts)
    return result

return timed
```

You can use it like this :

```
  @measure_time
  def foo():
        #content of function
```

note that `f.__name__` return the name of function ! (in this case 'foo')

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I now see where most of the time is going! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure the time spent on I/O only (ignoring the time spent on CPU), you could write a custom timer function:

```
import os

def io_timer():
    timing = os.times()
    return timing.elapsed - (timing.system + timing.user)
```

and pass it to the `cProfile`:

```
import cProfile, pstats

def profile_io_time(f, *args, **kwargs):
    prof = cProfile.Profile(io_timer)
    prof.runcall(f, *args, **kwargs)
    result = pstats.Stats(prof)
    result.sort_stats("time")
    result.print_stats()
```

You can use it then like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

profile_io_time(lambda: urlopen("https://google.com").read())
```